# LibreOffice displays the content of .docx files differently

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-word

Guys this is getting really annoying, i installed Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 11.10 just to use the office. Each time i want to write a document i reboot into Windows 7.
It's all because of the formatting i get when i write files in .docx using LibreOffice.
I tried everything that came to my mind, from resizing the page width and length, to changing the fonts and sizes. I always get a different formatting.
For example, **i get spaces where i did not put spaces ... The formatting is just different it looks so different than how it looks in Microsoft Word 2010.** I don't want to install Word using wine because when i used it back then on ubuntu it used to crash and caused me a lot of trouble.
And the most clear formatting error i get is with numbering.

### For example, i wrote:

```
1. anything
2. whatever
```

### when i save the file then reopen it in word i get:

```
1.1.1. anything
1.1.2. whatever
```

### then when i go back to LibreOffice it stays:

```
1.1.1. anything
1.1.2. whatever
```

I've searched everywhere but i couldn't find any solution. I hope this is easy to fix and i don't get it how no one experienced this before.

Comment: Formatting Issues between the two, nothing new really you should report this as a bug.

Comment: And for Compatibility issues, it's better to use .doc instead.

Comment: You could use MS office 2007 with playonlinux, is realy stable. it works well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, if you want MS Office compatibility, there's nothing better than MS Office. :(

However, I can maybe help you fix the rebooting problem, if your machine is up to it: install windows in a *virtual machine*. That's what I do.

All you need is a relatively modern processor that isn't meant to be for low power netbooks or something (i.e. not Atom, I think), and enough RAM to run both OS at once.

If you have that, then just install [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), create a new virtual machine using the simple GUI interface, insert your Windows CD, run the new blank VM, and install Windows, in a Window.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, i guess you're right, no product is as good as Microsoft's Office. It seems that i'll be going for a virtual machine.